# Am I able to create a form that is able to add a new django.contrib.auth User without logging in to the admin panel?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

Have created a form but unsure if is right and also unable to add a user, it will show TypeError/
[This is how the form I want it to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sx1Ns.jpg)

The following is my coding:

```css
class Form_Add_User(forms.Form):
    name=forms.CharField(label="Name", max_length=50)
    dateofbirth=forms.DateField(label="Date of Birth", widget=forms.widgets.DateInput(format="%m/%d/%Y"))
    contactnum=forms.CharField(label="Contact Number", max_length=9)

def adduser(request):
    if len(request.POST)>0:
        form=Form_Add_User(request.POST)
        if(form.is_valid()):
            name=form.cleaned_data['name']
            dateofbirth=form.cleaned_data['dateofbirth']
            contactnum=form.cleaned_data['contactnum']
            new_user=User(name=name,dateofbirth=dateofbirth,contactnum=contactnum)
            new_user.save()
            return redirect('/adduser')
        else:
            return render(request,'adduser.html',{'form':form})
    else:
        form=Form_Add_User
        return render(request,'adduser.html',{'form':form})
```

Answer (score 0):

First off: it's always **very** useful to also post a full error message if you have one. The more info you give us, the easier (and quicker!) is answering your question.

I assume, your `User` model is not actually django's auth User model (see, if you had posted the model, I wouldn't have to guess).
The form you pass to your template was not instantiated:

```
#...
else:
    form=Form_Add_User() #!!
    return render(request,'adduser.html',{'form':form})
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I'm trying to create a form using the django auth users. For my models I just simply imported it only and did nothing else.

Comment: The error that I get is
TypeError at /adduser/
'name' is an invalid keyword argument for this function
Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/adduser/
Django Version: 1.11.6
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value: 
'name' is an invalid keyword argument for this function
Exception Location: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py in __init__, line 573
Python Executable: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3.6
Python Version: 3.6.3

Comment: Please do not post error messages as a comment. Inlcude them in your opening post. If you are using the django auth model `User`, then of course this doesn't work. It doesn't have any fields like `name`, `dateofbirth` or `contactnum`. You will have to provides these yourself [by extending the User model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model)